# Efficient Calculation of Linear Feedback Shift Register Iterations

Tags: algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization, lfsr

I was wondering if it is feasible to determine the number of iterations required for the Linear Feedback Shift Register algorithm to generate the sequence let's say"1010" from the initial seed "1001," without the need to iterate through all possible values, given that the polynomial used is (x^4 + x^3 + 1).

To be ohnest I don't even know where to start, so i'll be thankful for any help.

Comment: Can't you just use a 256 value look-up table of pre-computed values?

Comment: No, beacause i want the algorythm to work with 64bit and more binary sequences, so there's no way.

Comment: This is essentially the discrete logarithm problem and can be quite hard depending on the mathematical setting. I'm not sure if it's hard in this case. See [Matrix form LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register#Matrix_forms) for example. There are square root algorithms, thus for 64-bit LFSR you could solve the problem in 2^32 steps.

Comment: i'm basically trying to create function, that would take seed and output binary sequence of LFSR and would return number of itterations it would take theLFSR algorythm to reach the output binary sequence, with help of some formula, so there is no need to iterate through all possible states.

Comment: This looks relevant but tldr,   https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/d4/02/7c/48332e333eb7c8/US20050135621A1.pdf It says under Summary Of Invention, In accordance with an aspect of the invention, there is provided a System, method, or computer program product configured determining the Nth State of an n-stage linear feedback shift register (LFSR)...

Answer (score 0):

For the given polynomial X^4+X^3+1 the feedback function of the shift register is the register state is written as (x0,x1,x2,x3) at instant k

f(x0,x1,x2,x3)=x0+x2

Hence the state map of the shift register is

x0(k+1)=x1(k),x1(k+1)=x2(k),x2(k+1)=x3(k),x3(k+1)=x0(k)+x2(k)

From the well known Golomb's condition the shift register is non singular i.e. the state map has an inverse. The inverse is given by

x0(k)=x2(k+1)+x3(k+1), x1(k)=x0(k+1), x2(k)=x1(k+1), x3(k)=x2(k+1)

Hence the reversed orbit from the state 1010 is the sequence:

(1010)-->(1101)-->(1100)-->(0110)-->(1011)-->(0101)-->(1010)

Thus the orbit does not have the state (1001). Hence the state (1010) cannot be reached from (1001).

In this method the computation of inverse of the shift register state map is an algebraic computation and is feasible in polynomial time in n the number of states. The orbit computation starting from a given state can be exponential if the orbit length through the final state x(T) has exponential length. Otherwise the reconstruction of the orbit is of polynomial time of the order equal to the orbit length. Hence reachability can be found out without enumerating all trajectories of the state evolution